# Data not returned from service if url has urdu characters in android

Tags: android

I want to fetch xml data from webservice having url like apps.google.com/واتس/main.xml in android, but the service doesn't returning data.does android support such type of encoding in urls or not?

below is the code to download the xml file from server, here sUrl[0] is the url to hit the server and it has some urdu characters.
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
      try {
          URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
          String androidPath=sUrl[1].toString().trim();
          URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
          connection.connect();
          int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
          InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
          OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(androidPath, "main.xml"));
          byte data[] = new byte[1024];
          long total = 0;
          int count;
          while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
              total += count;
              setProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

              output.write(data, 0, count);
          }

          output.flush();
          output.close();
          input.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
      return null;
}
```

Comment: There are so many things that can potentially go wrong here. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: is url working in desktop browser?

Comment: yes its working on desktop browser.

Comment: Don't swallow the `Exception` silently. It may give valuable hints on what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Henry, yes its going into catch block and e.getMessage() returns  the url we want to hit like apps.google.com/واتس/main.xml.

Comment: when i debug it goes to catch block from this line InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());